# Functional equation $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+(x+1)f(x)=1$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all functions $f$ such that $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+(x+1)f(x)=1,\space x\neq0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve this linear system on $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)$
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+(x+1)f(x)=1
$$
$$
f(x)+\left(\frac1x+1\right)f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1
$$
and get
$$
f(x) = \frac1{x^2+x+1}
$$

Comment: But is it the only solution? He asked for all the possible solutions for $f(x)$

Comment: @santa, it is because the linear system has only this solution.

Answer (score 5):

You must to change $x$ by $1/x$ and obtain a system.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

$$f\left(\frac1x\right)=1-(x+1)f(x),$$ so that
$$f(x)=1-\left(\frac1x+1\right)f\left(\frac1x\right)=1-\left(\frac1x+1\right)(1-(x+1)f(x)),$$and
$$f(x)=\frac1{(x+1)^2-x}.$$